# which relationship type should I use for venue type

Tags: laravel, database-design, laravel-5.5

I have an application that has venues each venue has one type I.E bar, cafe, restaurant etc

What type of relationship should I make this, I am having a moment of stupid.

It can't be one to one as there will be other venues with the same type. and it can't one to many as it only ever has one type.

Please feel free to point out what I am missing, I think it is something obvious.

Comment: One to many, one type can have multiple venues

Comment: so do I put hasmany on the type model and belongsTo on the venue?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Great. becasye you answered in a comment i can't mark you as providing the correct answer. add an answer and I will gladly mark is as correct.

Comment: Don't worry about it

Answer (score 0):

Real life scenario i know of a place i visit that has got a Bar, cafe, restaurant, gaming center, a small golf course, and a space for playing squash all in a Building. this venue is also used to host types of Party, corporate events, shoots e.t.c`enter code here`. all i am saying is the relationship between Venue to Venue type and Venue to Event type in a real time scenario is a Many to Many relationship one venue can belong to many venue types.

```
class Venue extends Model
{
    public function venuetypes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(VenueType::class);
    }
}

and on your VenueType Model
class VenueType extends Model
{
    public function venues()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Venue::class);
    }
}
```